# ADO.NET - How do I pass in a parameter to a stored procedure of type object

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net

If a stored procedure has a parameter of type object, how do I pass that in? Can I pass a Dictionary where the key is the property name and the value is the property value?

And what about objects that have a property that itself is an object? Is the value of that property then another Dictionary?

And if not a Dictionary, if I need to create this on the fly (I don't know in advance what the object type is. Usually I get it as a JSON object so I don't even have a class to map the object to)?

Comment: What does that mean `parameter of type object` Postgres doesn't have an object type?

Comment: The metadata for a parameter that postgresql returns says the parameter is of type object.

Comment: OK I'm intrigued: where do you get this metadata from? And what sort of parameter is it, an `OUT` param?

Comment: @Charlieface Ok, you're right. Object is used as a catch-all for types that are not standard. In the case of pagila that's: year, mpaa_rating, bpchar, jsonb, and some others. Any great ideas (we have a commercial library that supports this) for non-standard types?

Comment: I still don't get your use case. Which ADO provider are you using, Npgsql? Because that should map things correctly. Are you using `NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper`, what about `NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseJsonNet()`? You need to be much clearer about what is going on, please [edit] your post

Comment: @Charlieface We are using the Npgsql ADO.NET connector. But we're a commercial library where we can talk to and ADO.NET connector. We do not have any special code on a per connector level. So we don't use NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper, and can't because they may not have Npgsql installed on their system if they use another SQL database. So we have to work at the generic ADO.NET level, not anything Npgsql  aware.

Comment: Considering how much difference there is in the SQL used by different DBMSs, I would probably have separate classes to handle each one. Anyway, what database types are you returning, and what C# objects are you trying to map them to? Please be clear about this. As I said, the default providers map json/jsonb to string for example, so you need to explain what you are having trouble with